# Is Visual Studio Code Insiders still required for Julia users of the Jupyter extension?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

The Visual Studio Code extension for Jupyter notebooks lead me to this page and now I see that it is a "Python" page even though my question is about Julia. Sorry if this is inappropriate.

The VSC Jupyter extension page has long said that users of a Julia kernel should use Visual Studio Code Insiders, which I have been doing. However, it's a bit of a hassle to keep two versions of VSC up to date with especially settings, theme modifications, etc.

My question is: Superficial inspection seems to show that the Jupyter notebook extension with Julia works OK in VSC; is VSC-Insiders still required or recommended for Julia users? I'm at version 1.63 for both VSC and VSC-Insiders.

Answer (score 4):

No, I'm reasonably sure the only requirement at this point is that your VS Code version is at least 1.60.1.

Comment: I'll see if I can get a note in to have the "Insider" requirement changed on the doc page for the Jupyter extension.